# Export project module in command line

Tags: python, windows, shell, command-line

I was using all the time **without any problem** next command to run Python script within Linux. Including `pipenv` support.

```
pipenv shell
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<module>
```

Right now. I'm trying to run exactly the same source and Windows. **And it doesn't work.** Any suggestion? Please note. I was trying to set module in the entire `PATH` in the machine. But it didn't help either.

```
pipenv shell 
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;<module>
```

Below solution works, **but I don't want to use that**.

```
print(os.path.abspath(__file__ + "/../../"))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(__file__ + "/../../"))
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `set`?

Comment: @martineau What do you mean by `set`? It doesn't work, as I described above.

Comment: On Windows, the `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;<module>` does work. You can verify that by typing `set PYTHONPATH` immediately afterwards. However the change it makes is not permanent, and will be lost when you close the console.

Comment: @martineau I know it works to setup *environment variable*, obviously) Why question is why Python module cannot be loaded with exact same step as it works on Linux.